# pip install -e . gives error 13 in conda environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

While installing the development branch for sunpy on Ubuntu on wsl in a conda environment using miniconda3, the last command as per their [docs](https://github.com/sunpy/sunpy) `$ pip install -e .` terminates in `error 13: permission denied`.

All the miniconda files are owned by my user.

The whole error is :

> Obtaining file:///mnt/h/Documents/Projects/sunpy-git   Installing
>   build dependencies ... done   Getting requirements to build wheel ...
>   done
>       Preparing wheel metadata ... error
>       Complete output from command /home/akram/miniconda3/envs/sunpy-dev/bin/python
>   /home/akram/miniconda3/envs/sunpy-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py
>   prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpw4nipzaf:
>       running dist_info
>       writing /mnt/h/Documents/Projects/sunpy-git/pip-wheel-metadata/sunpy.egg-info/PKG-INFO
>       writing dependency_links to /mnt/h/Documents/Projects/sunpy-git/pip-wheel-metadata/sunpy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
>       writing entry points to /mnt/h/Documents/Projects/sunpy-git/pip-wheel-metadata/sunpy.egg-info/entry_points.txt
>       writing requirements to /mnt/h/Documents/Projects/sunpy-git/pip-wheel-metadata/sunpy.egg-info/requires.txt
>       writing top-level names to /mnt/h/Documents/Projects/sunpy-git/pip-wheel-metadata/sunpy.egg-info/top_level.txt
>       reading manifest file '/mnt/h/Documents/Projects/sunpy-git/pip-wheel-metadata/sunpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
>       reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
>       writing manifest file '/mnt/h/Documents/Projects/sunpy-git/pip-wheel-metadata/sunpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
>       creating '/mnt/h/Documents/Projects/sunpy-git/pip-wheel-metadata/sunpy.dist-info'
>       error: [('/mnt/h/Documents/Projects/sunpy-git/pip-wheel-metadata/sunpy.egg-info',
>   '/mnt/h/Documents/Projects/sunpy-git/pip-wheel-metadata/sunpy.dist-info',
>   "[Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/mnt/h/Documents/Projects/sunpy-git/pip-wheel-metadata/sunpy.dist-info'")]
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command "/home/akram/miniconda3/envs/sunpy-dev/bin/python
> ```
>
> /home/akram/miniconda3/envs/sunpy-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py
>   prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpw4nipzaf" failed with error
>   code 1 in /mnt/h/Documents/Projects/sunpy-git

But running the code from Anaconda prompt from windows doesn't give the error.

**Please note that all other error:13 post suggestions have not been helpful. Even uninstalling and reinstalling miniconda didn't help.**

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo` or adding the `--user` flag when using `pip`?

Comment: Verify that `/mnt/h` is not mounted read-only (must be `rw` in the output of `mount`). Verify that you have write permissions everywhere under `/mnt/h`.

Comment: @Carlos yes I've tried with both `sudo` and `--user` flags, but the result is the same.

Comment: @phd every output of `mount` is `rw` and I do have permissions everywhere under `/mnt/h`.

Comment: Can you confirm you have full access to the drive?  Please view this link for reference: https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-and-get-full-access-to-files-and-folders-in-windows-10/

Comment: @Carlos No I don't think I had full access to the drive as per the link. Anyway, I solved with admin rights as stated below in my answer. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It has to do with permissions of wsl and its ability to modify files on NTFS it seems. Came to this conclusion after reading the second part under **Bash on python** from this [post](https://joshpeng.github.io/post/wsl). The solution is to open the terminal (command prompt or cmder or hyper or any terminal) with admin rights by right-clicking on its icon and going through the same command as above.

Thanks @Carlos and @phd for replying quick, by the way.